# Flexslider 'smoothHeight' issue when window is resized?

Tags: jquery

I've successfully managed to get my flexslider to resize the slide based on height with the smoothHeight property. I was having trouble getting this to work but after researching online found that wrapping the function in `$(window).load` got it working.

I've set mine up so that it only happens if the window width is smaller than 769px.

My issue now is that the functionality only works when the page is loaded. If the window is resized from desktop down it doesn't work. Any ideas how I can get this working?

```
 if ($slider.length) {
   if ($(window).width() > 769) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $slider.flexslider({
         animation: 'fade',
         animationSpeed: 500,
         pauseOnHover: false,
         keyboard: true,
         touch: true,
         controlNav: false,
         directionNav: {{ settings.slider_home_arrows }},
         slideshow: {{ settings.slider_home_auto }},
         slideshowSpeed: {{ settings.slider_home_rate }}
       });
     });  
   } else {
     $(window).load(function() {
       $slider.flexslider({
         animation: 'fade',
         animationSpeed: 500,
         smoothHeight: true,
         pauseOnHover: false,
         keyboard: true,
         touch: true,
         controlNav: false,
         directionNav: {{ settings.slider_home_arrows }},
         slideshow: {{ settings.slider_home_auto }},
         slideshowSpeed: {{ settings.slider_home_rate }}
       });
     });
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS set the sliders `height: 100vh`

Comment: set this for the `.flexslider` class? That hasn't worked I think you may have misunderstood my question. I just need to script above to work when the window is resized. Any ideas how I can achieve that? Many thanks.

Comment: You need to control the width and height with CSS to make it responsive, styles set with JS are calculated on page load so they wont be responsive unless you write script that watches screen width and restyles accordingly

Comment: The images are responsive. The smoothHeight property controls the heigh or each slide and its caption by adjusting if say the type in the caption is longer. The script above does what I want but only on page load. When I resize the browser its like the smoothHeight function doesn't work. How would I achieve this with CSS? I thought I needed some sort of jquery function so that the above is triggered on window.resize? I'm just not great at this so didn't know where to begin.

Comment: hmm have you hooked up the flexslider CSS and not just the JS because I've used flexslider before and I remember it being responsive out of the box

Comment: Yep  I'm using the flexslider CSS. This demo shows what I'm trying to achieve. I've tried inspecting and they have the same as me. http://flex.madebymufffin.com/smooth-height/ Do you think there is something missing in my CSS then?

Comment: could you create a fiddle/codepen so I can see your code?

Comment: My set up is quite complicated I'll try having a look at the CSS to double check I'm not missing anything. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Thinking about it it could be to do with the way i have it setup in terms of only executing if window width is lower that 769px. Could that be it?

Comment: could well be, try setting up flexslider in isolation on a blank page without that restriction and see if the problem still arises

Comment: Above is how i have it. It probably isn't how it should be but I'm not great with jQuery.  I removed the top version and it seems to work but causes issue on my desktop version with other js i have in place.

Comment: It's because you've wrapped it within '$(window).load(function() {' the only difference between the two is whether smoothHeight is true or not declared? why not have create the if/else statement within the call to save repeating yourself?

Comment: Because for some reason the window.load causes issues on desktop with other js i have in my site. Does that mean i have a $window.load on something that doesn't need it in that case?

Comment: yep you don't window.load for flexslider, try removing all the other js and adding each function in back one by one to determine whats causing the issue